# Is there a way to detect incoming toll calls from Android?

Tags: android

Well,
I'm gonna try to explain what's my problem.
Here in Brazil we can make a normal call and the recieving person will pay for it.
I mean, A calls to B, then if B picks the phone, then he pays and not the one who called to him.
When A calls to B in this way he must prefix a number before the B's real number.
I mean, if B's phone number is 55555555, then A needs to call him like this: 909055555555.

When i check it in incoming calls, it appears only as normal number of A without any information about it.
Does anyone know how to detect this kind of call?

Answer (score 0):

Try this link

http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/

Essentially, you register for the [android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) intent and check for the extra on the intent for [EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)  to get who is dialing you. (your java code and then look at the number and do any decision making.)

The link notes that

> TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER. This variable contains the incoming phone number. Note that this variable will not be present when the state is not TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.

I assume that the user need to pick up the call for your application detect the number, which may be a deal-braker for you.

**UPDATE**

I understand your question better now. It seems like the transformation to the real number from 9090* number is done by your cellular operator. I don't think you have a way to detect it, because your phone doesn't see a difference between the two calls. It sees them as the same caller. You may have a better answer if you talk to your cellular operator.

Comment: Yeah... Im getting my calls the way that you said here... But my problema is that i cant detect when the caller used 9090 to call... Thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't think you can detect that from within the phone. As I understand, the translation happens hidden to the phone, at the cellular career. You;kk have to talk to them.